# Number of results needed from each node in parallel processing

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I have a dataset (in the form of a file) composed of lines of words. I want to find the 20 more frequently occurring words. This is a huge dataset so I am processing this in parallel. Now I would partition the dataset into subsets and feed them into each parallel worker. Each parallel worker would then find the counts of each word and return a list of the most frequent words with their counts. Then all the lists would be aggregated and the top 20 most frequent words out of the entire dataset would be compiled from the results of each worker.

How many word/count pairs does each worker need to return to the aggregator in order to guarantee that I will get the top 20 words out of the entire data set?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do?  If I understand correctly, you want to be able to stop processing after dealing with a certain percentage of your total input data, correct?

Comment: no, i want to know how much of the data each worker needs to return. the algorithm would need to process all the data regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to say. Consider, for example, the possibility that you have four workers and worker 1's word frequencies are the inverse of the other three workers' frequencies. In order to get an accurate count, worker 1 will have to return its *entire* data set so that it can be aggregated.

In the general case, each worker has to return all of its data to the master node for aggregation.

What you're doing is a pretty typical map and reduce problem, a good discussion of which can be found at [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) or [Map/Reduce - A visual explanation](http://ayende.com/blog/4435/map-reduce-a-visual-explanation).

Answer (score 1):

You need to process all of the words until the difference between the 20th and 21st most frequent words is greater than the number of unprocessed words remaining.

If you need to rank the top 20 most frequent words, then you need to process everything.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: also, how would you know how many words are remaining unless you processed them to get their counts in the first place?

Comment: @Transcendence - My point is that you are barking up the wrong tree.  There is no fixed number of word/count pairs that "each worker need to return to the aggregator in order to guarantee that I will get the top 20 words out of the entire data set".  If you can keep a global count of what has been processed so far, and what is remaining, then you can stop all of your workers early when the difference between the 20th and 21st most frequent words is greater than the number of unprocessed words remaining.  Otherwise, process everything.

Comment: that goes back to my 2nd comment. how would you even know how many words are remaining unless you processed them in the first place if i don't even know what's in the dataset, much less what the distinct words are?

so you're just pretty much saying process everything, because everything else you're saying doesn't seem to be applicable.

Comment: @Transcendence - You haven't provided any details about your "dataset".  For example, if it is a data structure, most data structures provided a constant-time way to get the count of the number of elements.  If it is a database table, then you can query to get the count.  What is the nature of your dataset that doesn't allow you to know the count without iterating through every element?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's a file.